# Low performance retrieving calendar events in comparison to contacts

Tags: c#, rest, graph, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently testing some functionality (performance,...) of the graph api (using graph C# sdk) and got curious about something.
When I tried to request a large number of calendar events it took a long time compared to when i accessed contacts. 
The attached image contains a statistic, that compares completion times of large amounts of contacts and calendar events (using graph sdk). 
I found that the difference between them is quite big even if its just 1000 units that are requested (events: 13s vs. contacts: 2s).
The code I used for both requests should be pretty much identical (as seen below). 
I also tested sending my own HTTP-Requests (without graph sdk) but still got similar results.

Since the returned JSONObjects of calendar events and contacts seem not that different in size, i wanted to ask if there is a reason why the contacts can be requested so much faster?
And how I could improve the performance for retrieving events?

Code for getting contacts of specific folder:

```
//request contacts from contactfolder with id = contactFolderId
var request = m_graphClient.Me.ContactFolders[contactFolderId].Contacts.Request().Top(1000);
var result = await request.GetAsync();
//add result to a list
contacts.AddRange(result);
//send nextLink request if available
var nextPage = result;
while (nextPage.NextPageRequest != null)
{
    var nextPageRequest = nextPage.NextPageRequest;
    nextPage = await nextPageRequest.GetAsync();
    contacts.AddRange(nextPage);
}
```

Code for getting calendar events of a specific calendar:

```
//request events from calendar with id = calendarFolderId
var request = m_graphClient.Me.Calendars[calendarFolderId].Events.Request().Top(1000);
var result = await request.GetAsync();
//add result to a list
events.AddRange(result);
//send nextLink request if available
var nextPage = result;
while (nextPage.NextPageRequest != null)
{
     var nextPageRequest = nextPage.NextPageRequest;
     nextPage = await nextPageRequest.GetAsync();
     events.AddRange(nextPage);
}
```

image: [image: time comparison with graph sdk]

Comment: Isn't events may be coming from recurrent events too? The API have to calculate it.

Comment: The events requested are not recurring events just singleInstance, but i also tested recurring events. I got similar results for those too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Stack Overflow isn't a discussion forum and (as best I can tell) there really isn't a programming question here.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur 
 
May i ask how i can improve my message. I thought this was the place to ask this question (developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview)‌​. To be more precise, i want to know how i can improve my code to request calendar events faster.